# Where is the direction of acceleration in a body moving in 1 dimension?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, particle-accelerators

like where is the direction of acceleration if a car is moving in a straight line or if an object is thrown upwards (its direction if acceleration) ?

Comment: Do you mean the object is thrown upwards from an accelerating car?

Comment: Direction of acceleration of particle on a rigid body is a tricky thing to describe when it comes to rotations. In your case, there is pure translation and thus all particles move cohesively and accelerate similarly. Is this the scenario you are describing?

Answer (score 1):

The direction of acceleration for the car depends on the choice of acceleration of the driver of that car. An object thrown upward near the surface of Earth always experiences a constant downward acceleration of 9.8 m/s^2.